# How to load array value int cell without creating multiple custom cell in UITableView iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have multiple label in tableview. Created an array for label left side. now i am trying to load data from array model for each label. But it says index out of range, cause it model array index is 0.

Here is my model :

```
 class PrItemDetailModel {

var Material: String?
var Description: String?
var FixedVendor: String?
var VendorName: String?
var PurchOrg: String?
var PurchGroup: String?
var qtyUoM: String?
var valuationPrice: String?
var TotalValue: String?
var DeliveryDate: String?
var MatGrp: String?
var Plant: String?
var StorageLocation: String?
var ReqTrack: String?
var AAC: String?
var ItemCategory: String?
var GLAccount: String?
var CostCenter: String?
var Order: String?
var WBS: String?
var ProfitCenter: String?


init(Material: String?, Description: String?, FixedVendor: String?, VendorName:String?, PurchOrg: String?, PurchGroup: String?, qtyUoM: String?, valuationPrice: String?, TotalValue: String?, DeliveryDate: String?, MatGrp: String?, Plant: String?, StorageLocation: String?, ReqTrack: String?, AAC: String?, ItemCategory: String?, GLAccount: String?, CostCenter: String?, Order: String?, WBS: String?, ProfitCenter: String?){

    self.Material = Material
    self.Description = Description
    self.FixedVendor = FixedVendor
    self.VendorName = VendorName
    self.PurchOrg = PurchOrg
    self.PurchGroup = PurchGroup
    self.qtyUoM = qtyUoM
    self.valuationPrice = valuationPrice
    self.TotalValue = TotalValue
    self.DeliveryDate = DeliveryDate
    self.MatGrp = MatGrp
    self.Plant = Plant
    self.StorageLocation = StorageLocation
    self.ReqTrack = ReqTrack
    self.AAC = AAC
    self.ItemCategory = ItemCategory
    self.GLAccount = GLAccount
    self.CostCenter = CostCenter
    self.Order = Order
    self.WBS = WBS
    self.ProfitCenter = ProfitCenter

    }

 }
```

Here is array created for label:

```
   var PrItemTitleLblArray = ["Material#", "Description", "Fixed Vendor#","Vendor Name", "Purch Org", "Purch Group", "Qty | UoM", "valuation Price", "Total Value", "Delivery Date", "Mat Grp", "Plant", "Storage Location", "Req Track#", "AAC", "Item Category", "G/L Account", "Cost Center", "Order", "WBS", "Profit Center"]
```

Here is the array from model:

```
  var prItemArray = [PrItemDetailModel(Material: "", Description: "Bottles", FixedVendor: "KP04", VendorName: "KP Suppliers", PurchOrg: "1000", PurchGroup: "002", qtyUoM: "40.000 EA", valuationPrice: "EUR 40.00", TotalValue: "EUR 1,600.00", DeliveryDate: "09/12/2014", MatGrp: "00807", Plant: "1100", StorageLocation: "", ReqTrack: "", AAC: "Cost Center", ItemCategory: "0", GLAccount: "000040000", CostCenter: "0000010000", Order: "", WBS: "0000000", ProfitCenter: "0000001402")]
```

Here is the code which i have used in tableview:

```
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! PrItemCellTableViewCell

       cell.material.text = PrItemTitleLblArray[indexPath.row]
       cell.materialvalue = prItemArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
```

Here is screenshot which i want to achieve: [image]

here is my json response:

```
 "results": [
  {

   "PoDocNo": "4500022400",
   "Item": "00010",
   "Material": "RMECC_MOB1",
   "StorageLocation": "3001",
   "MatGroup": "00107",
   "Quantity": "2.000",
    "OrderUnit": "KG",
   "NetPrice": "1000.000",
   "UnitofPrice": "1.000",
   "ItemCat": "0",
   "Requistor": ""
   },
  {

  "PoDocNo": "4500022400",
  "Item": "00020",
  "Material": "RMECC_MOB1",
  "StorageLocation": "3001",
  "MatGroup": "00107",
  "Quantity": "2.000",
   "OrderUnit": "KG",
  "NetPrice": "1000.000",
  "UnitofPrice": "1.000",
  "ItemCat": "0",
  "Requistor": ""
  }
  ]
```

Any help much appreciated pls...

Comment: Is your goal to have multiple `PrItemDetailModel` items? So you have Material#", "Description", "Fixed Vendor#", ... "AAC" for each item? Or, is your table just a list of Labels -> Values for a single `PrItemDetailModel`?

Comment: @DonMag tableview with list of labels and and single values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Parameswaran V

Here below check my simple updated answer for **Can you suggest me best way for above one while passing json**

You can create the Structure to form your required record like below,

```
    struct DemoItems {

        var key: String?
        var value: String?
    }

fileprivate var demoItems: [DemoItems]?

fileprivate func loadDemoItems() -> [DemoItems] {

        var tempItems = [DemoItems]()

        let item1 = DemoItems.init(key: "Material#", value: "")
        let item2 = DemoItems.init(key: "Description", value: "Bottles")
        let item3 = DemoItems.init(key: "Fixed Vendor#", value: "KP04")
        let item4 = DemoItems.init(key: "Vendor Name", value: "KP Suppliers")
        let item5 = DemoItems.init(key: "Purch Org", value: "1000")

        tempItems.append(item1)
        tempItems.append(item2)
        tempItems.append(item3)
        tempItems.append(item4)
        tempItems.append(item5)

        return tempItems
    }
```

In viewDidLoad like,

```
    demoItems = loadDemoItems()

    if let tempDemoItems = demoItems {

        print(tempDemoItems)
        print(tempDemoItems[0].key)
        print(tempDemoItems[0].value)
    }
```

Output:

```
[permisdesauver_dev.DemoItems(key: Optional("Material#"), value: Optional("")), permisdesauver_dev.DemoItems(key: Optional("Description"), value: Optional("Bottles")), permisdesauver_dev.DemoItems(key: Optional("Fixed Vendor#"), value: Optional("KP04")), permisdesauver_dev.DemoItems(key: Optional("Vendor Name"), value: Optional("KP Suppliers")), permisdesauver_dev.DemoItems(key: Optional("Purch Org"), value: Optional("1000"))]
Optional("Material#")
Optional("")
```

So your cell.material.text = tempDemoItems[indexPath.row].key & cell.materialvalue.text = tempDemoItems[indexPath.row].value

Hope it's help you!

Comment: Thanks for answering.. it show error when use return method Contextual type '[[String : Any]]' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Comment: also can you say me how to use this code for my project

Comment: @ParameswaranV can you try with my Edited answer. It means seems your output have `key & values` have forming like dynamic contents handled with a single array of objects.

Comment: In viewdidload demoItems is unresolved identifier.. Use of unresolved identifier 'demoItems'; did you mean 'DemoItems'?

Comment: Seems you missed declaring like `fileprivate var demoItems: [DemoItems]?`

Comment: i have another doubt, I have up and down arrow. When i click up arrow load another set of array in labels and again tapping on down arrow it load previous array of labels. how to do that..

Comment: Hi ram, how to my json response value into value?

Comment: @ParameswaranV make an iteration (if it's an array Otherwise you can assign) with your json response value to form your PrItemDetailModel.

Comment: i have upated my json reponse, can you tell me how to use it, let item1 = DemoItems.init(key: "Material#", value: "")

Comment: @ParameswaranV if your response like as Dictionary or array of dictionaries use iteration and parse it should be like 
let resultValue = yourDictionaryInstancep["correspondingKey"] 
let item1 = DemoItems.init(key: "Material#", value: resultValue)
Hope it's clear to you :)

Comment: hi ram i could not able to make it.. i haveprivate var poVendorItemArray = [PoVendorModel]() i have appended json response value into poVendorItemArry using swiftyjson, dont know how to use it in key, value. can you pls update your answer

Comment: Hi @ParameswaranV here **let item2 = DemoItems.init(key: "Description", value: "Bottles")** I have set dynamic values on `key & value`, so you must get the `key` also dynamic on your web service Otherwise you need to append dynamic key based on your Json response count. Hope you have cleared it :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating an array of Label Strings, and then you *think* you are creating an array of Values... but you're only creating an array of ***ONE*** `PrItemDetailModel` object.

Consider this (I've simplified your class to make it easier to see):

```
class PrItemDetailModel {

    var Material: String?
    var Description: String?
    var FixedVendor: String?

    init(Material: String?, Description: String?, FixedVendor: String?) {

        self.Material = Material
        self.Description = Description
        self.FixedVendor = FixedVendor

    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // create array of Label Strings
    var PrItemTitleLblArray = ["Material#", "Description", "Fixed Vendor#"]

    // create array of PrItemDetailModel objects
    var prItemArray = [PrItemDetailModel(Material: "", Description: "Bottles", FixedVendor: "KP04")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this will print "3"
        print(PrItemTitleLblArray.count)

        // this will print "1"
        print(prItemArray.count)

    }

}
```

So when you try to fill rows in a table, your first row - `indexPath.row` equals `0` - your codes says:

```
// get the "Label String" from the array of Label Strings
// at index 0, this will be "Material#"
cell.material.text = PrItemTitleLblArray[indexPath.row]

// get the "Value String" from the array of PrItemDetailModel objects
// at index 0, this will be AN OBJECT, not a String
cell.materialvalue = prItemArray[indexPath.row]
```

The next row - `indexPath.row` equals `1` - your codes says:

```
// get the "Label String" from the array of Label Strings
// at index 1, this will be "Description"
cell.material.text = PrItemTitleLblArray[indexPath.row]

// get the "Value String" from the array of PrItemDetailModel objects
// at index 1 ... ERROR, because prItemArray has only one element
cell.materialvalue = prItemArray[indexPath.row]
```

You probably want to re-think your data structure... Where will you be getting these values? Via json from a server? From a database? You might be better off simply storing the data in an array of Dictionaries.

Or, and this is just *one other way* to approach it... modify your class to return values based on indexing:

```
class PrItemDetailModel {

    var Material: String?
    var Description: String?
    var FixedVendor: String?

    init(Material: String?, Description: String?, FixedVendor: String?) {

        self.Material = Material
        self.Description = Description
        self.FixedVendor = FixedVendor

    }

    func getProperty(at index: Int) -> String {

        switch index {
        case 0:
            return self.Material ?? ""
        case 1:
            return self.Description ?? ""
        case 2:
            return self.FixedVendor ?? ""
        default:
            return "Error"
        }

    }

}
```

You would then change your code to:

```
    // create ONE PrItemDetailModel object
    var prItem = PrItemDetailModel(Material: "", Description: "Bottles", FixedVendor: "KP04")
```

and in `cellForRowAt`:

```
// get the "Label String" from the array of Label Strings
cell.material.text = PrItemTitleLblArray[indexPath.row]

// get the "Value String" from the array of PrItemDetailModel objects
// based on the index
cell.materialvalue.text = prItem.getProperty(at: indexPath.row)
```

Comment: It works fine. Thanks for your suggestions. Can you suggest me best way for above one while passing json. Now i have used 2nd method..